# Spring RestTemplate not accepting JAXBElement

Tags: spring, resttemplate, jaxb2

I am trying to make a simple POST using RestTemplate to a service. The XSD that I have, does not generate the Root Element but instead has the Root Element Type. But ObjectFactory.createFoo(FooType) gives me the JAXBElement which I am trying to post but failing to do so with below exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [com.foo.FooType] and content type [application/xml]
```

This is my code which calls the rest service

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
                    HttpEntity<FooType> entity = new HttpEntity<FooType>(request.getValue(),headers);
                    JAXBElement<ResponseType> response = restTemplate.postForObject(esbReplaceNumberListURI, entity, JAXBElement.class);
```

I tried adding Jaxb2Marshaller(of Spring O/X jar ) to RestTemplate with setSupportJaxbElementClass set as true after going through an answer in StackOverflow. That did not help.

I am building my request object as below which gives me JAXBElement

```
  JAXBElement<FooType> request =  ObjectFactory.createFoo(FooType);
```

and then while posting I do a request.getValue() as below:

```
HttpEntity<FooType> entity = new HttpEntity<FooType>(request.getValue(),headers);
```

My Spring Config as below:

```
@Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(getMarshallingHttpMessageConverter());
        return restTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public MarshallingHttpMessageConverter getMarshallingHttpMessageConverter() {
        MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingConverter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
        marshallingConverter.setMarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller());
        marshallingConverter.setUnmarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller());
        marshallingConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML));

        return marshallingConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setSupportJaxbElementClass(Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.foo.domain.*");
        return marshaller;
    }
```

Using Spring-Boot 1.3.5.RELEASE which in turn uses Spring 4.2.6.RELEASE.
I am at my wits end in figuring this out. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm about 75% sure that you should have `marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.foo.domain");`, not `marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.foo.domain.*");`. Note the absence of the `*` - I believe that it's attempting to find a package whose name literally is `*`, which obviously doesn't exist.

Source:

`Jaxb2Marshaller#setPackagesToScan`:

> This is using a Spring-bases search and therefore analogous to Spring's component-scan feature `({@link org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner})`

That suggests it's probably the same as described in the [Spring Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-scanning-autodetection), which says:

> The following is an alternative using XML
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
>     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
>         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
>         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
>         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
>
>     <context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>
>
> </beans>
> ```

Which has `<context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and +1 for giving detailed info on package declaration. I changed it as per your suggestion. Still see the same exception. Also I tried giving directly the class name which is FooType. Getting the same error.

Comment: Ahh, I see it now! You shouldn't pass `request.getValue()` - you should just pass `request`. I suspect that `FooType` is missing the `@XmlRootElement` annotation, which is why it has to be wrapped in a `JAXBElement`. Thus, `HttpEntity<JAXBElement<FooType>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(request, headers);` (assuming Java 7+).

Comment: HttpEntity<JAXBElement<FooType>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(request, headers); doesnt work either for me.