# Spring Boot and configureMessageConverters

Tags: spring-boot

I'm facing an issue related to Spring Boot + data converters. So, basically I want to
validate application/xml requests against xsd that are coming to an endpoint called
`/request/test`.

My Configuration file

```
package com.my.package.configuration;

import com.test.AcceptMessageRequestType;
import com.test.AcceptMessageResultType;
import com.test.ObjectFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import javax.jms.Session;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ReqConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final Logger LOG =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReqConfiguration.class);


    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(customConverter());
    }

/* NOT WORKING
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        try {
            converters.add(customConverter());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
*/

    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverter<Object> customConverter() {
        MarshallingHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
        xmlConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
        xmlConverter.setMarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller());
        xmlConverter.setUnmarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller());
        return xmlConverter;
    }


    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        jaxb2Marshaller.setSchemas(
                new ClassPathResource("/MyMessageResponse.xsd"),
                new ClassPathResource("/MyMessageRequest.xsd"));
        jaxb2Marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(MyMessageRequest.class,
                MyMessageResponse.class);
        jaxb2Marshaller.setValidationEventHandler(event -> {
            event.getMessage();
            LOG.info("Do something");
        });
        jaxb2Marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jaxb2Marshaller;
    }

}
```

relevant part of my pom file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency> WORKS BUT NOT bypasses jaxb2Marshaller and no validation happens
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>-->
```

Rest endpoint

```
@PostMapping(path = "/request/test", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody MyResponseMessage acceptMessage(@RequestBody MyRequestMessage message) {

   return null;
}
```

xsd generated classes (cxf-xjc-plugin plugin)

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MyResponseMessage", propOrder = {
    "result",
    "uuid",
    "accepted"
})
public class MyResponseMessage implements Serializable {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Result result = new Result();
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String uuid;
    protected boolean accepted;
     <... setter / getter cut out ...>
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "result", propOrder = {
    "result",
    "desc"
})
public class Result implements Serializable {

    protected int code;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String desc;
<... setter / getter cut out ...>
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AcceptMessageRequestType", propOrder = {
    "id",
    "name",
    "state"
})

public class MyRequestMessage implements Serializable {

@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String id;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String name;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String state;
   <... setters / getters cut out...>
}
```

So, all I get is either 415 (unsupported type), or if I use jackson, I get the response, but the validation of an incoming request is not validated against xsd. How to make so that the incoming
xml request would be validated against xsd?

**Update no.1**

it seems that this question is similar, but it does not work for some reason...

[attempted solution](http://Returning%20JAXB-generated%20elements%20from%20Spring%20Boot%20Controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[BAD SOLUTION BEGIN]**

Okay, so what I did was

Step no.1

```
package com.my.package.configuration;

import com.test.AcceptMessageRequestType;
import com.test.AcceptMessageResultType;
import com.test.ObjectFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import javax.jms.Session;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ReqConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final Logger LOG =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReqConfiguration.class);


    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(customConverter());
    }

@Override //ADD THIS INSTEAD
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    try {
        converters.add(customConverter());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/* NOT WORKING
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        try {
            converters.add(customConverter());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
*/

    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverter<Object> customConverter() {
        MarshallingHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
        xmlConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
        xmlConverter.setMarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller());
        xmlConverter.setUnmarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller());
        return xmlConverter;
    }


    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        jaxb2Marshaller.setSchemas(
                new ClassPathResource("/MyMessageResponse.xsd"),
                new ClassPathResource("/MyMessageRequest.xsd"));
        jaxb2Marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(/*path to ObjectFactory.class(-es)*/);
        jaxb2Marshaller.setValidationEventHandler(event -> {
            event.getMessage();
            LOG.info("Do something");
        });
        //jaxb2Marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jaxb2Marshaller;
    }

}
```

Step no. 1.5 add Maven entries

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Step no.2 refactor your endpoint to accept String and return String

```
@PostMapping(path = "/request/test", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String acceptMessage(@RequestBody String message) {
        final XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    final StringReader reader = new StringReader(message);
   jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(new StAXSource(inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(reader)));
   return null;
}
```

And everything should be validated now by xsd

**[BAD SOLUTION END]**

All what was needed to do is

in a block where I defined jaxb2Marshaller add         `jaxb2Marshaller.setSupportJaxbElementClass(Boolean.TRUE);`

And just use JAXBElement for input and accordingly to the output.

Also, remove maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and controller becomes

```
@PostMapping(path = "/request/test", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody JAXBElement<OUTPUT.class> acceptMessage(@RequestBody JAXBElement<INPUT.class> message) {
// do something with a validated message object
}
```

Solution is based on this post [Spring RestTemplate not accepting JAXBElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481225/spring-resttemplate-not-accepting-jaxbelement)

**Update no.1**

Spring Boot 2.4.0 does not require `@EnableWebMvc`, so you can skip it